# Redireccionar a app play store desde html

Tags: javascript, android, php, html

quisiera saber cómo puedo abrir mi app directamente en el google play store.

Sucede que tenemos una aplicación que posee un WebView apuntando al sitio de nuestra empresa, en el sitio de nuestra empresa estamos colocando el código que figura más abajo (ese es un sitio de pruebas), es ahí en donde detectamos en función del package si está utilizando la app, al detectar que utiliza nuestra app deseamos enviarle un mensaje de alerta y que lo redireccione a la app play store para que descargue una nueva app nuestra.

Muestro mi codigo html para poder explicarme de mejor manera.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/global_js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">    </script>    

<title>APP</title>


<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "com.ejemplo.cooperativa"){
echo 'estás desde la app';  
//$ch = curl_init("market://details?id=com.ejemplo.cooperativa");
//curl_exec($ch);

echo "   <SCRIPT>window.location.href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?     id=com.ejemplo.cooperativa&feature=search_result#?';</SCRIPT>"; 
}

else{
echo 'NO estás desde la app';
}
?>


</head>
<body >

</body>
</html>
```

Espero se haya entendido.

Me figura el siguiente error :

[no muestra http://imageshack.com/a/img924/1170/H8Kbqo.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img924/1170/H8Kbqo.png)

De antemano Muchas Gracias.

Comment: ¿Pero estando dentro de tu app o en el sitio de tu empresa?

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta

Comment: Si usas el navegador de tu teléfono, puedes usar el   `userAgent`

`if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1) {
    if(confirm("¿Descargar la nueva app?")) {
        window.location.href= "market://details?id=<packagename>";
    }
}`

Comment: es válido para un webview?

Comment: Se supone que eso está para el navegador nativo de Android, debe de funcionar.

Comment: Ah y otra cosa en tu imagen dice "ejemplo.cooperativa" ¿Así se llama tu paquete? Me parece que olvidaste cambiar el nombre de tu package. de **com.ejemplo.cooperativa** a **tuPackage.cooperativa**

Comment: si, mi paquete se llama así dado que es uno de pruebas.

Answer (score 1):

La estructura es la siguiente: `market://details?id=com.package.tuapp`
Con este esquema Android abrirá directamente en Playstore el detalle de tu app

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, edité mi pregunta para que observes en código lo que estamos haciendo.

Comment: Asumo que quieres que los usuarios ingresen a una web, si es desde el escritorio, que ingresen a la web de google play, si es desde móviles, que los lleve a la aplicación de google play. En ese caso, debes hacerlo a través de User-Agent para detectar si es por Android o por Escritorio y redirigir en base a eso

Comment: nuevamente edité mi pregunta, añadiendo más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo mejor es generar el botón y lo colocas dentro de tu html para redireccionar a Google Play donde esta tu aplicación.

Para generar el botón podes ir a https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  window.location.href='market://details?com.ejemplo.cooperativa';
</script>
```

Sino también:

```
<script>
  window.location.replace('market://details?com.ejemplo.cooperativa');
</script>
```

Incluso puede ser un link:

```
<a href="javascript: window.location.replace('market://details?com.ejemplo.cooperativa');">
  Ver app
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sino también:

```
<script>
  window.location.replace('market://details?com.ejemplo.cooperativa');
</script>
```

Incluso puede ser un link:

```
<a href="javascript: window.location.replace('market://details?com.ejemplo.cooperativa');">
  Ver app
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu código tienes un detalle:

```
<SCRIPT>window.location.href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?     id=com.ejemplo.cooperativa
```

la variable id no debe estar separada en la url, debe ser:

```
<SCRIPT>window.location.href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ejemplo.cooperativa
```

#### Como abrir una aplicación de la playstore desde una página web.

Desde una página web puedes realizarlo mediante:

```
<script>
  window.location.href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ejemplo.cooperativa';
</script>
```

ó

```
<script>
  window.location.replace('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ejemplo.cooperativa');
</script>
```

Otra opción es usando el protocolo `market://`, pero **este método únicamente funciona dentro de un dispositivo android** ya sea en una página web o un webview.

```
<script>
  window.location.replace('market://details?id=com.ejemplo.cooperativa');
</script>
```

Puedes revisar la **[documentación](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html)** para ver más detalles.

> Desde un sitio web:
>   `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<nombre_paquete>`
>
> Desde una aplicación Android: 
>   `market://details?id=<nombre_paquete>`

Ejemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Abrir aplicación Playstore</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ejemplo.cooperativa">Abre con http://<a>
<br>
<a href="market://details?id=com.ejemplo.cooperativa">Abre con market://<a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: publiqué una respuesta en donde muestro el error que me sucede.

Comment: ok Rodrigo, trata de agregar las actualizaciones a tu pregunta original :)  Es lo que comento en mi respuesta, el protocolo market:// únicamente sirve en un dispositivo Android! , usa h ttp://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<nombre_paquete>

Comment: la captura de imágen es de mi dispositivo Android, al ingresa esa URL me envía a la versión web del google play, pero queremos que nos envíe directo a la app del google play para que el usuario realice la instalacioón

Comment: @Rodrigo he visto tu problema me parece que es un bug de tu dispositivo https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170880 usa la opción ; /play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<nombre_paquete> , que sistema operativo es tu Dispositivo?

Comment: estamos probando en un emulador del android studio que tiene la version 6.0 y en un dispositivo físico con android 5.0.1

Comment: ok, ya probaste con ttp://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<nombre_paquete> ???

Comment: si probé como me lo indicaste pero me figura el error net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: En lugar de market: usa http:, con http no debe fallar y funcionaria tanto en web como en un webview, de hecho se ve en tu imagen que estas usando "market:  //"